# How to match part of a string to a regex in bash?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, scripting

I am using a regular expression to match many file names with similar names. See the files below.

```
file1="CGInoimport"
file2="doCGIimport"
file3="donoCGInoimport"
file4="importCGIno"
```

I am using a `for` loop to iterate through each file variable to check if the regular expression matches. I am trying to isolate file name containing the word `CGI`. Here is what I have so far.

```
for (( i=1; i < 5; i++ )) ; do
    if [[ file$i =~ ^CGI$ ]] ; then
        echo "There is a CGI in the name"
    else
        echo "This shouldn't happen"
    fi
done
```

The problem is for each `file`, I am getting `This shouldn't happen`. I know there is a problem with the regular expression but I don't know how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Let me know if further explanation is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex `^CGI$` only matches when the **entire** string is `CGI`. If you want to match any substring, use simply `CGI`.

This is because in a regular expression, `^` only matches at the beginning of a string ("anchors" to the beginning), and `$` only at the end. That said, it's more conventional to use shell-style patterns here (with the `=` operator rather than `=~`), and simply use wildcards to disable their implicit anchoring.

Finally, since you want to look up through a variable lookup, you need to use variable indirection. So:

```
varname=file$i
if [[ ${!varname} = *CGI* ]]; then
  echo "There is a CGI in the name"
fi
```

That said, the *better* way to do it would be to use an array. So:

```
files=( CGInoimport doCGIimport donoCGInoimport importCGIno )
for file in "${files[@]}"; do
  [[ $file = *CGI* ]] && echo "There is CGI in the name $file"
done
```

...or, if the keys can be non-numeric or discontiguous, an associative array:

```
declare -A files=(
  [file1]=CGInoimport
  [file2]=doCGIimport
  [file3]=donocCGInoimport
  [file4]=importCGIno
)
for key in "${!files[@]}"; do
  [[ ${files[file$key]} = *CGI* ]] && echo "There is CGI in $key"
done
```

Comment: @Alias, ...please see the additions, discussing use of arrays, associative or otherwise. Usually, an array is a better replacement for any case where you'd be using indirection.

Comment: Do you  know why using an associative array is better for indirection matching?

Comment: @Alias, the advantage of using an associative array is that you're less likely to run into namespace collisions, and they're easier to populate and manipulate safely (without being tempted to use `eval`). Also, they can have arbitrary keys, rather than being limited to keys that are also valid shell variable names. That said, since you're just using numeric keys, you don't need your array to be associative in this specific case; I showed them for completeness.

Comment: You can use `${!files[@]}` to iterate over the keys directly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I appreciate your help and will note down your advice. Thanks.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the adjustment!

Comment: I initially generated keys explicitly to match the original code's behavior -- but on consideration, iterating over the full defined set is indeed more in line with intent.